# Sinch is not supporting video call in swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, sinch

here is my code.  I covert this code from objective c to swift from the sinch test` Giving the Objective-C part might be interesting to help but it's not supporting video call. when i accept the call audio is working fine. but video is not sending to the other device. please help me out if any one has the sample code for swift then send or try to fix it with this code.. thanks

```
// MARK: - Load
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if call?.direction == SINCallDirection.incoming {
        self.callStateLabel.text = ""
        self.showButtons(EButtonsBar.kButtonsAnswerDecline)
        //audioController().startPlayingSoundFile(path(forSound: "incoming.wav"), loop: true)
    } else {
        self.callStateLabel.text = "calling..."
        self.showButtons(EButtonsBar.kButtonsHangup)
    }
    if  (call?.details.isVideoOffered)! {
        localVideoView.addSubview(videoController().localView())
        localVideoFullscreenGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: switchCameraGestureRecognizer)
        videoController().localView().addGestureRecognizer(localVideoFullscreenGestureRecognizer)
        videoController().remoteView().addGestureRecognizer(remoteVideoFullscreenGestureRecognizer)
    }
}

@IBAction func accept(sender: AnyObject) {
    call?.answer()

}

@IBAction func decline(sender: AnyObject) {
    call?.hangup()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func hangup(sender: AnyObject) {
    call?.hangup()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func audioController() -> SINAudioController{
    return Global.client.audioController()
```

}

```
func videoController() -> SINVideoController {
    return Global.client.videoController()
}
```

Comment: ` I covert this code from objective c to swift from the sinch test` Giving the Objective-C part might be interesting to help if you didn't translate correctly a line.

Comment: @Larme help me out

Comment: @HassanShahid Have you checked all methods of demo ? Please make sure those all are available in your swift code.

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya yes i have checked all the methods.. i debug it again and call it in objective c app.The issue is video is not receiving in in swift app. Video is sending successfully

Comment: @HassanShahid I checked same and its working fine. Make sure you are calling video call method. let call: SINCall? = self.callClient().callUserVideo(withId: recipientName)

Comment: @HassanShahid is it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 Views in your view controller. One is for local video view and another one is for remote video video. Set it outlets to view controller. I have a working audio call example and i just add this things to my call view controller.

```
func videoController() -> SINVideoController {
    return appDeletgate.client.videoController()
}
```

In viewdidload check for if video is offered by call.

```
if call.details.isVideoOffered {

    localVideoView.addSubview(videoController().localView())
    //localVideoFullscreenGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: switchCameraGestureRecognizer)
    //videoController().localView().addGestureRecognizer(localVideoFullscreenGestureRecognizer)
    //videoController().remoteView().addGestureRecognizer(remoteVideoFullscreenGestureRecognizer)
}
```

Add this method to add remote video in view.

```
func callDidAddVideoTrack(_ call: SINCall?) {
    remoteVideoView.addSubview(videoController().remoteView())
}
```

Also make sure you add this 2 keys into info.plist

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) need to access your camera for video call.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses the Microphone for calling</string>
```

And this is finally how i call it.

```
let call: SINCall? = self.callClient().callUserVideo(withId: recipientName) //self.callClient().callUser(withId: recipientName)
let callVC  = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CallVC") as! CallVC
callVC.call = call
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(callVC, animated: true)
```